# Double integral area.

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I have to do $$\int\int_D{\rm d}x\,{\rm d}y$$ where D is between $y=2x^2-2$ and $y=1-x^2$.
I draw my area and my new integral become:
$$\int_{1-x^2}^{2x^2-2}\int_{-1}^{1}{\rm d}x\,{\rm d}y$$.
I switched the boundaries:
$$\int_{-1}^{1}\int_{1-x^2}^{2x^2-2}{\rm d}y\,{\rm d}x$$.After solving this i end up with a negative value.I shouldn't get a negative value so my question is what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Your inner bounds are backwards. "$2x^2-2$" should be on the bottom and "$1-x^2$" on the top.

Comment: Bounds should go "lower" to "upper". Notice that $y=2x^2-2$ is a parabola which opens upward and $y=-x^2+1$ is a parabola which opens downward. Thus $2x^2-2$ should be a lower bound and $1-x^2$ an upper bound.

Comment: One more thing...the first integral which you wrote down with order of integration: $dx\,dy$ is wrong for other reasons. You should never have a variable of integration appear in a bound for an integral outside where it appears as the variable of integration -- for a problem like this only numbers should appear as outermost bounds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you drow the graph, you will see that for $x\in [-1,1]$,

$1-x^2\geq 2x^2-2$ so  you should have $$\int_{-1}^{1}\int^{1-x^2}_{2x^2-2}{\rm d}y\,{\rm d}x$$

Comment: @user137209: you are welcome.